# ¿Como Hacer dos listas desplegables que dependan de otro lista desplegable?

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas tardes necesito hacer en una plantilla html tres listas desplegables(select) donde dos de ellas dependen de la primera seleccion que se escoja.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solucion que encontre es muy sencilla desde el onChange pude invocar las dos funciones javascript(separandolas por punto y coma).

Answer (score 1):

Yo actualmente estoy utilizando PHP, HTML y jQuery. Te voy a explicar (Dentro de los comentarios del código) de la manera más fácil que pueda para que lo logres comprender.

En mi caso, tengo 2 select uno que llamaremos Institución y otro que llamaremos area: Uno que contiene el nombre de las instituciones, y que cuando seleccione la institución, el siguiente select nos mostrará las areas/carreras que contiene la institución.

```
<?php
  //Hago la consulta a la base de datos de instituciones
  $query = 'SELECT * from instituciones';
  $result = $connection->query($query);
?>
   <select class="form-control" name="institucion" id="institucion" required>
       <option>Selecciona una institución</option>
          <?php
               //Despliego todos los registros de mi consulta con el ciclo While
               while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
          ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $row['idinstitucion']; ?>">
                    <?php  //Muestro el nombre de la institucion
                         echo $row['nombre']; 
                    ?>
              </option>
          <?php
             }
          ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="area">Area</label>
       <select class="form-control" name="area" id="area" required>
          <option>Selecciona el area</option>
       </select>
</div>
```

Si te das cuenta, mi primer select contiene un ID llamado institucion y el segundo select contiene un ID llamado area. Y ahora empieza lo bueno con jQuery...
Dentro de jQuery ira esto:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#institucion").change(function(){ //Evento que se activa cuando selecciono el ID de institución
      var institucion=$(this).val(); //Obtenemos el valor de institucion

//Envio a una página que hara la consulta SQL y me devolvera los datos
$.get("http://localhost/asignaturas/procesarasignaturas.php?idinstitucion="+institucion,
           function(data){
                $("#area").html(data); //Le decimos donde queremos mostrar el resultado que se hara en la pagina.
           });
 });
});
```

¿Qué hay en procesarasignaturas.php? Bueno, es donde nosotros haremos la consulta para nuestro select llamado #area, el cual se activará cuando nosotros seleccionemos nuestro select llamado #institucion.

```
<?php
 include('connection.php');
 //Obtenemos el valor del evento GET que pusimos en JQuery
 $idinstitucion = $_GET['idinstitucion'];
 //Hacemos nuestra consulta MySQL.
 $sqlarea = "SELECT * FROM area WHERE idinstitucion='$idinstitucion'";
 $consultatipo = $connection->query($sqlarea);
?>

         <option>Selecciona el area</option>
    <?php
         while($query = $consultatipo->fetch_array()){
    ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $query['idinstitucion']; ?>">
              <?php echo $query['area'];?>
         </option>
```

Espero y te sea de ayuda. Por favor, si tienes cualquier duda, si no te quedo claro o algo que pueda hacer, estoy dispuesto a ayudar. Saludos! :D